# Dynamically set/manipulate max-height to avoid scrollbar at outer container

Tags: javascript, html, css

The snippet below gives me two vertical scrollbars, one at `dialogBox` and the other at `withLongContent`.

How can I set/manipulate `max-height` of `withLongContent` so that there will be no scrollbar at `dialogBox`? That is, the height of `withLongContent` and that of "up stuff" togther do not exceed `dialogBox`'s height (90vh in this example).

CSS-only solution is preferred, then vanilla JS one. I cannot adopt jQuery.

```html
<div id="dialogBox" style="max-height:90vh; overflow:auto;">
  Arbitrary inline and block elements here. Let's call them "up stuff".
  <table rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom:1rem;"><tbody>
    <tr><th scope="col">ID</th><th scope="col">Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td>014436</td><td>Name1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>402723</td><td>Name2</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">"up stuff" ends here.</td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
  
  <div style="display:inline-block">
    <div id="withLongContent" style="max-height:90vh; overflow:auto;">
      A dynamic long list of stuff here:
      <ol>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One way is to remove the `overflow:auto` from `dialogBox` and setting the `max-height` of `withLongContent` to something smaller like `max-height:90vh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a `flex-box`:

```css
#withLongContent { 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    overflow: scroll;
}

#dialogBox { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height:90vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogBox">
  Arbitrary inline and block elements here. Let's call them "up stuff".
  <table rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom:1rem;"><tbody>
    <tr><th scope="col">ID</th><th scope="col">Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td>014436</td><td>Name1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>402723</td><td>Name2</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">"up stuff" ends here.</td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
  
 
  <div id="withLongContent">
    A dynamic long list of stuff here:
    <ol>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```